# How to get property of an object

Tags: javascript

I'm creating an empty array and fill it with object.

```js
export const model = [
    {isMine: false},
]

const newArr = Array(25);
newArr.fill(model);
newArr.forEach((item) => {
    console.log(item);
})
```

This logs out all objects with the array. But I don't know how to log out the `isMine` property... I always get undefined

Comment: Are you sure `model` should be an array?

Comment: I do think you need to study the basic of programming, strong sense that you are achieving goal in a wrong way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this is what you need. If you `spread` `(...)` the `model` it will get stored as objects. But if you don't `spread` it will be stored as an array inside an array which contain an object

```js
const model = [
    {isMine: false},
]

const newArr = Array(25).fill(...model);
newArr.forEach((item) => {
    console.log(item.isMine);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps, you need to access array inside array

```js
const model = [
    {isMine: false},
];

console.log(model[0].isMine);

const newArr = Array(25);
newArr.fill(model);

console.log(newArr);

newArr.forEach(x => x.forEach(y => console.log(y.isMine)));
```

Answer (score -1):

`newArr` is a 2 dimensional array, since `model` is an array.

So to access the property `isMine` in your `forEach` loop you'd do:

```
newArr.forEach((item) => {
  // item is an array, so get the value at the first index
  console.log(item[0].isMine);
})
```